# Why the "Convert class" has no definition in my IDE?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am developing a simple app for Android using the Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015. I am using c# as a language. I want to convert a string to an int. But the `Convert` class has no definition in my IDE. I want to write the following:

```
int ress = Convert.ToInt32(num1.Text)+ Convert.ToInt32(num2.Text);
```

Here is a picture of what I am having.
Why I am having this problem? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You may be missing a using statement at the top of your class:

```
using System;
```

Or you can write the full class name:

```
System.Convert.ToIn32(num1.Text);
```

Or you can use:

```
int.Parse(num1.Text)
```